# I failed to open my xp backup bkf file in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp, ntbackup, backup

I moved xp backup bkf file to windows 7, but could not open bkf file through NTBackup restore utility because I received an error message “the backup file contains unrecognized data and cannot be used”.

How can I open bkf file in Windows 7 that were created in Windows XP?

Answer (score 3):

I'm fairly certain that an NTBACKUP from Windows XP isn't compatible with Windows 7. You probably need the [Windows NT Backup Restore Utility for Windows 7 and for Windows Server 2008 R2](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/974674).

> The utility restores backups that are made on Windows XP and on Windows Server 2003 to computers that are running Windows 7 and Windows Server 2008 R2.